# Python script is crashing after writing initial set of words

Tags: python, automation

I am attempting to write a program that automates the keyboard speed test website. However, the program crashes after writing the first initial set of words which is displayed when the website is first opened. After that, it does not write anything. I have tried multiple solutions, but none of them have been effective.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english")

    # Wait for the page to fully load
    time.sleep(6)

    # Find the text input element on the page
    text_input = driver.find_element("id", "inputfield")

    current_word = driver.find_element("id", "row1")
    print(type(driver))  # <-- Add this line
    # Type the words into the input field
    while True:
        text_to_type = current_word.text

        for character in text_to_type:
            text_input.send_keys(character)
            time.sleep(0.1)

        # Check if the next sibling element exists
        next_word = current_word.find_element_by_xpath("following-sibling::span[1]")
        if not next_word:
            break

        current_word = next_word

    # Submit the form to complete the typing test
    text_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)

finally:
    # Close the web browser
  driver.quit()
```

First I thought browser is blocking automatic typing. In order to mimic human writing I added random delay between each code.

```
for word in text_to_type:
        for character in word:
            text_input.send_keys(character)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.05, 0.1))
        text_input.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1.0))
```

Then I thought maybe website updates itself after first initial line and tried to update whole block with this code but it didn't help.

```
while True:
        # Get the next word to type
        word_elements = driver.find_elements("css selector", "#row1 span")
        if not word_elements:
            break
        word = word_elements[0].text
```

So basically I could able to solve this problem. I am adding full code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english")

    # Wait for the page to fully load
    time.sleep(6)

    # Find the text input element on the page
    text_input = driver.find_element("id", "inputfield")

    # Find all the words to type
    words = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//span[@wordnr]")

    # Type each word into the input field
    for word in words:
        text_to_type = word.text
        for character in text_to_type:
            text_input.send_keys(character)
            time.sleep(0)
        text_input.send_keys(" ")
        time.sleep(0)

    # Submit the form to complete the typing test
    text_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)

    #finally:
        # Close the web browser
     #   driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The words you get from `driver.find_element("id", "row1")` aren't the complete list of words, even before the test starts.  It looks like that result only includes words that are visible in the "words" div.  There are more words hidden on the page but can be found by inspecting the page.

Your last attempt should have worked.  I get a list of ~380 elements that contain the words you are looking for when I run `driver.find_elements("css selector", "#row1 span")`.  Some small adjustments to your typing implementatino to add in the spaces between each word and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I could able to solve problem by myself. I will ad comment and add edits that I made. It works pretty good.